# Timezone issue converting date to "Today", "Yesterday", "2 days ago", etc. in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, calendar, momentjs

I have a news feed and I want to display the time an article is published simply as Today, Yesterday, 2 days, 3 days ago, etc. I just want to preserve the YYYY-MM-DD format and get rid of the timezone part. However at 8pm NYC Eastern Time (ET) the dates change for example from 2 days ago to 3 days ago. How can I make sure that this change is only made at midnight ET every day?

An example of an article date: 
2020-03-17T04:00:00.000Z

Current code:

```
 convertDateLiteral(article_date: string) {
    const newDt = article_date.split('T')[0];
    let date = moment(newDt);
    if (moment({hours: 0}).diff(date, 'days') >= 2) {
            return date.add(1,'d').fromNow(); // '2 days ago' etc.
    }
    //console.log(date.calendar().split(' ')[0])
    return date.calendar().split(' ')[0]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given dates strings in ISO 8601 format, you can convert to Date objects, zero the time, then compare to today's date with zeroed time and rounding for daylight saving changes, if any. E.g.

```js
function getEvenDaysDiff(d) {
  let now = new Date();
  now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  let then = new Date(d);
  then.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return Math.round((now - then) / 8.64e7);
}

function parseAndFormatDate(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  let z = n => (n<10?'0':'')+n;
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' +
         z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
         z(d.getDate());  
}

// test - dates are UTC so local dates may differ
let dates = [
 '2020-03-17T04:00:00.000Z',
 '2020-03-16T14:00:00.000Z',
 '2020-03-12T04:30:00.000Z',
 '2020-02-17T12:00:00.000Z'
].forEach(
  s => console.log(parseAndFormatDate(s) + ' ' + getEvenDaysDiff(s) + ' days ago.')
);
```

Note that as the timestamps are UTC, the date they represent may be different to the equivalent local date. I've assumed you want differences to local dates. If you want UTC, then use UTC methods in *getEvenDaysDiff* and the *parseAndFormatDate* function is superfluous.